# Screen Capture of HTML/JS Application - Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, google-maps, screenshot

I would like to create a button that takes screen captures of a map applicaiton. The map is built using Google Map JS API.

[This is a fiddle to a simple example that could be used to demonstrate screengrab functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/vdpQ7/)

```
var map;

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
mapOptions);
```

I spent a lot of time trying to create a screengrab function using the [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
 lib but had a difficult time creating a proxy. For this reason I am exploring other screengrab options.

Would it be possible to create the screen grab function using silverlight? Could I somehow incorporate silverlight into my application for the screen grab function? Any other suggestions?

Comment: How about first replacing the map canvas with an image from the google static maps API, and only then taking the screenshot with html2canavs.

Comment: e.g: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-34.397,150.644&zoom=7&size=600x300&sensor=false